# Algorithm to find load distribution to NAPTR DNS queries

Tags: algorithm, dns, load-balancing

I have the following problem:

I have 5 servers, where I want to load balance them with 60% for the first server and 10% for the other fours servers.

I use NAPTR DNS entries to answer these servers.

All 5 servers will have the same ORDER but will have different PREFERENCE values to achieve the load balance weight.

According to RFC2915:

> Preference is
>         A 16-bit unsigned integer that specifies the order in which NAPTR
>         records with equal "order" values SHOULD be processed, **low
>         numbers being processed before high numbers.**

My difficult is to find out which value should the field PREFERENCE receive for each load balance percentage.

Does anyone know how to do the maths on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the rest of the quote: *This is similar to
      the preference field in an MX record*

Which means the algorithm is quite simple: the client uses the lowest number, try to connect based on the content. If it succeeds, end of algorithm, if it fails go back at beginning using the next lowest number. Until they are no more entries.

So the values themselves are meaningless, they can be configured in any way the administrator likes. What is important is their relative value between each other, just to be able to order the set from an authority standpoint.